# Database not Updating Values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that can only have one record per user. The condition I'm using to determine if the user has a previous submission isn't writing to the database for some reasons. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $anthem1 = null;
    $cointoss2 = null;
    $firstscore3 = null;

    //$query

    $query  = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM mypicks ";
    $query .= "WHERE user_id = {$user_id} ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if (isset($result)) {

            //existing submission -  this is breaking it    
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


                if (isset($_POST['anthem1'])) {
                     $anthem1 = $_POST['anthem1'];
                }       

                if (isset($_POST['cointoss2'])) {
                     $cointoss2 = $_POST['cointoss2'];
                }       

                if (isset($_POST['firstscore3'])) {
                     $firstscore3 = $_POST['firstscore3'];
                }   

                $query  = "UPDATE mypicks SET";
                $query .= "anthem1 = '{$anthem1}', ";
                $query .= "cointoss2 = '{$cointoss2}', ";
                $query .= "firstscore3 = '{$firstscore3}' ";
                $query .= "WHERE user_id = {$user_id} ";
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            }

            }else{

            //new submission    
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


                if (isset($_POST['anthem1'])) {
                     $anthem1 = $_POST['anthem1'];
                }       

                if (isset($_POST['cointoss2'])) {
                     $cointoss2 = $_POST['cointoss2'];
                }       

                if (isset($_POST['firstscore3'])) {
                     $firstscore3 = $_POST['firstscore3'];
                }   

                $query = "INSERT INTO mypicks (";
                $query .= " user_id, anthem1, cointoss2, firstscore3";
                $query .= ") VALUES (";
                $query .= "  '{$user_id}', '{$anthem1}', '{$cointoss2}', '{$firstscore3}'";
                $query .= ")";
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                }   
            }
?>
```

Comment: are all fields filled ? what about if isset returns false ?

Comment: Have you tried to add a space after "SET", it looks like a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're missing a space after SET

```
            $query  = "UPDATE mypicks SET";// Concats as SETanthem1
            $query .= "anthem1 = '{$anthem1}', ";
            $query .= "cointoss2 = '{$cointoss2}', ";
            $query .= "firstscore3 = '{$firstscore3}' ";
            $query .= "WHERE user_id = {$user_id} ";
```

Second, building on what v7d8dpo4 says, you'll want to do something like $result->num_rows or if you'd like fetch and rowCount. But that's not relevant to your question on updating

Third, you can prevent errors like this in the future by simply testing the query through the UI of phpmyadmin or whatever you'd like

Answer (score 0):

According to https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

So `isset($result)` will always be true. To see if `$result` is not empty, use `$result -> num_rows`.